# How to capture the output of one shell script into other in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I am running one shell script **run_sftp.sh** 
whose output will be either "done" or "failed" 
and I am calling this script into another script which will execute some command if **run_sftp.sh** output is "done"

```
If [ Output(run_sftp.sh) = 'done' ] then
  echo "run"
else
  "Stop running"
fi
```

This is the algorithm. Please suggest.

Comment: Why not have the other script return zero for success instead?

Comment: I didnt get your question. can u please elaborate ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

like this?

```
retval=$(path/to/run_sftp.sh)
```

now you have done/failed in var `retval`. you can do your if check with your logic.

Comment: I am executing other commands also so there will be other outputs except Done and Failed, but I want to capture only done, then in that case how should I capture only done from command output?

Comment: regex match check @Pooja25

Comment: I am using `retval=$(sh run_sftp.sh)` `cat $retval | grep "Done"` but it is not working

Comment: it won't work, if you want to use grep, try `grep -qi "done" <<< $retval` and check the return code of the grep. @Pooja25

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the output using $(), or the inverse `

So:

if [ $(run_sftp.sh) = 'done' ]
then

etc

Comment: I am executing other commands also so there will be other outputs except Done and Failed, but I want to capture only done, then in that case how should I capture only done from command output?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your script run_sftp.sh will call other statements and produce done message only when it is success and no other commands called by run_sftp.sh will produce done message.
In that case you capture output of script run and then grep done

```
MSG=$(run_sftp.sh)
echo $MSG | grep 'done'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "run"
else
exit 9
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)